# Adding French doors in bedroom and bathroom. Can I do this without structural engineer?

Tags: walls

I would like to add french doors in my bed room and my bathroom.  I am not sure if I would need a structural engineer for this.  I have my blueprints of my bedroom and bathroom.
If I sent picture could you let me know if it is causing me to get an engineer and if I am damaging the structural part of the house?

Comment: First you need to determine if it’s a bearing wall. Is it a 2 story house?

Comment: Are there doors or windows there now that you'd be replacing? Is the bedroom upstairs or downstairs?

Comment: You need a framing pan or to be able to reconstruct on paper or in your head how the roof/upper floor is supported by the walls.